# Triggering formula in excel on the values entered using python (openpyxl module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a worksheet as : [EXCEL-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r69Zl.png)

Where, I am entering values in cell 'A2' and 'B2' using python, and expecting the total in cell 'C2', where excel formula is embedded.

```
import openpyxl  
path = r"path of file"  
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)  
sheet=wb_obj.get_sheet_by_name('Summary Sheet')  
sheet['A2'] = 200  
sheet['B2'] = 300    
wb_obj.save(r"path of file")
```

After running above code, my worksheet looks like : [EXCEL-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozA1.png)
Able to update the value in cell, but formula in cell 'C2' is not getting triggered, to print the sum of cell 'A2' and 'B2' .

How can we trigger the embedded formula using python ?

Comment: Why the `\\` before brackets

Comment: Updated the code . (might got added while uploading code )

Comment: What do you want to perform?